# Cocoa "tab view" control? (beginner)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am looking for the "tab view with icons" control as shown below. Is it a standard control or how do I get it? I didn't find it in Interface Builder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a tab view per se, but a toolbar which has been configured to work like one.